# Dynamically access file in dataflow pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using a dataflow pipeline and I'd like to be able to access files on it.

this is the line where I call method to get files and extract modules:

```
def run():
    """ Run pipeline"""
    options: PipelineOptions = PipelineOptions(
        project='production-213911',
        runner='DataflowRunner',
        region='europe-west1',
        streaming=True,
        setup_file='dataflow/setup.py',
        autoscaling_algorith='THROUGHPUT_BASED',
    )
    proto = Container().protobuf()
    test = proto.get_proto_file('data/build')    
    proto.get_obj_from_file(test)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
        ...
```

this is the pipeline step where I'd like to use my module's list:

```
        status_records = (status | 'Proto to Dict' >> beam.Map(
        lambda x: convert_proto_to_dict(x, proto.protos)))
```

and here is the code that browse the directory to get files:

```
@staticmethod
def get_proto_file(dirname: str = 'python_protocol') -> List[object]:
    """Iterate threw dir w. build .proto
    :param
        dirname = name of the directory to browse
    :return
        List[object] with module
    """
    protos: List[object] = []
    for root, _, mod in os.walk(dirname):
        for name in mod:
            if 'pb2' in name and 'pyc' not in name:
                print(name)
                module = name[:-3]
                if '/' in root:
                    dirname = root.replace('/', '.')
                path = f'{dirname}.{module}'
                imported_module = importlib.import_module(path)
                protos.append(imported_module)
    return protos
```

However my 'proto.protos' variable is always set to None (meaning test is None, I am sure the problem is on the first step)

I tried to call this line from a file on the same level as my pipeline and it works:

```
test = proto.get_proto_file('data/build')
```

So I am guessing this is because my files are not in dataflow as they are in my project..
Any idea how to do this ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a common problem.

- Firstly, you have to understand how beam works. When you prepare your pipeline, you are on the main server there is all your code, all your files. The pipeline is built (Yes, your pipeline is compiled/translated in Java for efficiency reason, Python is too slow (if the new runner is already deployed, your code is compiled in C++, but anyway, the Python disappear at runtime) and ship it to the worker servers with the pipeline option.
- Then, you should understand the issue: the compiled pipeline and the options are shipped, not your files!

**How to solve this?**

Because the pipeline option are sent with your compiled pipeline, load your file in the main server (before your pipeline start) and store the content into the pipeline option.

The read it from the option in your transform

Comment: I am so sorry but I do not understand what you mean by 'load your file in the main server', I tried to create a tmp folder, does not work, try to load the module, does not work either..

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear. So, with these lines you can read your file content, `test = proto.get_proto_file('data/build')    
    proto.get_obj_from_file(test)` right? If so, just after these lines, store the content of the file (the proto) into the PipelineOption object. Then in your pipeline, get the content from the PipelineOption. (I know how to extend the PipelineOptions type in Java, not in Python, but the principle is the same)

Comment: Oh the confusion is from me, With my methods I just get module and classes in it. As I do not manage to do what I want Ithink I will try to upload my file to a bucket